# How to correctly convert TAG value to the right format so that to Verify HMAC?

Tags: c, hash, hmac

I'm working on HMAC generation and verifying to check data integrity. I can correctly generate the MAC value but when sending it through socket to another program for verification, I faced with formatting mismatch. I appreciate your support. Thanks.

```
unsigned char* MAC(unsigned char* key,unsigned char* message)  
{
    unsigned char* result;
    unsigned int result_len = 32;  
    int i;        
    result = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * result_len);
    result = HMAC(EVP_sha256 (), key , strlen (key), message , strlen(message) , NULL, NULL);   
    return result;
} 

int verifyMAC(unsigned char* key,unsigned char* message, unsigned char* receivedTag)
{
    printf("\n\n ==================== MAC Verification ==================\n\n");
    unsigned char* newHash; // newly generated hash value
    unsigned int newHash_len = 32;  
    int  i,flag=0;   
    newHash = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * newHash_len);
newHash = HMAC(EVP_sha256 (), key , strlen (key), message , strlen(message) , NULL, NULL); 
    for (i=0; i!=newHash_len; i++)
    {
            if (receivedTag[i]!=newHash[i])
            {
                printf("DATA MISMATCH: Found %02X instead of %02X at index %d!\n", newHash[i], receivedTag[i], i);
                break;
            }
    }
    if (i==newHash_len)
    {
        printf("MAC verified!\n");
        flag = 1;
    } 
    return flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    unsigned char* key = "1234567890";
    unsigned char* message = (unsigned char*) "hello world";
    …
}
```

Console result:

```
Hashed data:  E4  5F  60  72  61  7C  CE  5E  06  A9  5B  E4  81  C4  33  51  02  3D  99  23  35  99  EA  C9  FD  AF  FC  95  81  42  62  9A 


==================== MAC Verification ==================

DATA MISMATCH: Found E4 instead of 65 at index 0!
ERROR: data is modified
```

Comment: What programming language is that? $\;$

Comment: please note: your MAC verification is vulnerable to timing attacks as you immediatly fail after one byte's wrong which allows attackers to forge MACs with only a few trials (~4k).

Comment: @RickyDemer  It is in C language

Comment: although I don't really like your programming style, I don't see any reason why verification should fail. Did you verify the network connection code is good? Did you verify if verification succeeds if you just pass the results of the first function to the second? If it succeeds your network code may be broken.

Comment: The network connection doesn't have a problem. I think the problem is with converting char* mac value to hex value. 
In the main() function, i called the verifyMAC function with  `verifyMAC(key, message, "\xe4\x5f\x60\x72\x61\x7c\xce\x5e\x06\xa9\x5b\xe4\x81\xc4\x33\x51\x02\x3d\x99\x23\x35\x99\xea\xc9\xfd\xaf\xfc\x95\x81\x42\x62\x9a") ` and verifies correctly. 
But, when char* variable is initialized with this hex value, it generates the hex integer value of each characters (\, x, e, 4 ...).
`char* mac = "\xe4\x5f\ ... \x9a";  
verifyMAC(key, message, mac) `

Comment: It’s definitely a C coding issue, not a cryptographic one – which is why I‘ve migrated this question to Stackoverflow.

Comment: The question is already posted [How to correctly convert TAG value to the right format so that to Verify HMAC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760965/how-to-correctly-convert-tag-value-to-the-right-format-so-that-to-verify-hmac)

Comment: What I think is, 65 hex is 'e'. so, convert the hex to corresponding string with lower case A-F. Then Check the result. Or, you can inversely change the received tag to corresponding hex.